# Using select2 with vuejs directive, data from html

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, jquery-select2

I have tried to create a vuejs2 directive, which would pick the already rendered select and wrap it into select2. This part is working but doesn't pick the selected value:

```
Vue.directive('select', {
    inserted: function (el) {

        $(el).select2({
            matcher: modelMatcher,
            minimumResultsForSearch: 6,
            dropdownAutoWidth: true,
            width: 'auto'
        });

    }
});
```

Any ideas how to do this? This probably worked with vuejs 1:

https://gist.github.com/themsaid/c0548e19f247b832ac4f

but not working any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `select2`, when changed, throws a [**`jQuery.Event` Object**](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), and **Vue only reacts to regular JavaScript events**.

So the solution is to, after initializing select2, listen to the `change` `jQuery.Event` it emits and emit a `change` `CustomEvent` as well, so Vue picks it up.

When Vue picks the `change` `CustomEvent`, it will update the `v-model`.

Demo below.

```js
Vue.directive('select', {
  inserted: function(el) {
    var self = this;
    $(el).select2({
      //matcher: modelMatcher,
      //minimumResultsForSearch: 6,
      //dropdownAutoWidth: true,
      width: 'auto'
    }).on('change', function(e) {
      if (e.detail === "vue-directive") {
        return; // prevent stack overflow (i.e. listening to the event we threw ourselves)
      }
      // throw regular change (non jQuery) event, so vue reacts
      el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("change", {
        detail: "vue-directive"
      }));
      return false;
    })
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    states: ["AL", "AK", "AZ"],
    selectedState: "AK",
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedState" v-select>
    <option v-for="state in states" :value="state">{{ state }}</option>
  </select>
  <p>Selected State: {{ selectedState }}</p>
</div>
```

Note that's just one way of doing it, there's a great variety of possibilities, making use of [Vue's Custom Directives **Hook Functions**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Hook-Functions). Also note that the example I show above is sligthly simpler than the gist you provided, as it does not handle the `unbind` hook, for instance. The implementation should be straightforward, OTOH.

Comment: Thanks! What I was trying to achieve was more like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/mg4zr2Ly/4/

But your answer helped me to accomplish it.